# How to make line graph from x-axis values versus y-axis values in xcode?

Tags: xcode4, xcode5

How to create x-y graph with x-axis values for example x1,x2,x3 versus y-axis values for y1,y2,y3?

Comment: Well you could always draw using UIBezierPath or CGContext. Did you look into those?

Comment: Sorry no i am very new to app developing.

Comment: If you are new to app developing, I suggest you take a course on it to learn more about it. My recommendation is taking Paul Hegarty's Stanford iOS Programming Course. He is a really good teacher and the course is free. If you just want to learn drawing concepts, I have attached a link for you to look at from Apple's site:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html